# Outlook+Excel: Download attachments from multiple emails and audit them against an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, adobe-acrobat

Every time a client completes an online form, I receive an automatic confirmation email with a PDF attachment of said form containing an ID number unique to them. I have about 600 of these emails. I also have a spreadsheet of people who *should* have completed the form. I have about 1900 of these people. So, I need to identify on the sheet the 1300 people who have not completed the form.

The problem is, because the ID numbers are hidden in the attached PDF and not apparent in the email subject or body, it's actually impossible to tell what ID number is represented by the email unless the PDF is opened.

The 'manual' way to do this would be to search the ID number in Outlook, which can read the PDFs and tell me whether a PDF with their ID number is in the folder or not. However, I don't want to this hundreds of times.

I thought I could mass export all the email data to a CSV and then conditional format the dupes to easily see which values have matches and which don't, but I was only able to export sender, subject line, and content. And again, it's impossible to differentiate the emails by their subject and content alone. Unfortunately, the PDF must be read.

So, I am looking for a way to:

1. Mass download all attached PDFs from the emails
2. Compare the column of IDs in the sheet to the IDs contained in the PDFs, preferably not by hand

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly understand that I know little about Excel, but as far as the Outlook client is concerned, I notice that you need to save all PDF attachments locally.

I think the automatic reply email containing PDF may have a same or similar subject. It's suggested that you could refer to the method of **saving attachments using VBA** mentioned in this thread *@JadeLiang MSFT*: [Save attachment Outlook Desktop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/486726/save-attachment-outlook-desktop.html#:%7E:text=Please%20first%20understand%20here%20we%20mainly%20focus%20on%20general%20issues%20on%20Outlook%20desktop%20client%2C%20for%20your%20script%20issue%2C%20I%20have%20researched%20a%20lot%20and%20found%20we%20could%20set%20a%20rule%20with%20specific%20conditions(such%20as%20particular%20sender%20and%20subject)%20and%20run%20a%20script%20in%20it%20like%20below%20to%20meet%20it.).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.